# php loop while increasing value

Tags: php

I have an rather simple php code which I would like to change into an loop (if possible). Otherwise the code will be too long at the end. Unfortunately I am not really familiar with php (the code is for an Online questionaire).

```
if (value('X001_03') == 1) {  
    question('VAR', array(1));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 2) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 3) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2,3));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 4) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2,3,4));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 5) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2,3,4,5));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 6) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 7) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
} elseif(value('X001_03') == 8) {
    question('VAR', array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
}
```

Basically the number after == has to increment by "1" until it reaches 9, while the range of the arrays increases at the same time.

Thankful for any help!

Best regards

Comment: [`range()`](http://php.net/range) might help...

Answer (score 12):

Should not need a loop, you should be able to replace the whole thing with just

```
question('VAR', range(1, value('X001_03')));
```

[`range(x, y)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) allows you to create an array containing values from x to y.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer!  Do I understand it correctly that I still would have to write one line for every if condition? Like: question('VAR', range(1, value('X001_03')));
question('VAR', range(2, value('X001_03'))); and so on?

Comment: no. This single line replace all your if{}elseif()... structure.

Comment: No, this replaces the code you had shown completely. `range(1,1)` gets you the equivalent of `array(1)`, `range(1,2)` gets you the equivalent of `array(1, 2)`, and so on - so this makes any loops completely superfluous at this point.

Comment: okay, nice! But with that i still get an error here: question('VAR', range(1,9, value('X001_01'))); Sorry, probably a stupid question, but as I mention- I am pretty much a beginner with php.

Comment: range takes two parameters, not three. You probably meant `range(1, value('X001_01'))` in that place?

Comment: Accept if you found it useful, as others might have the same error as you.

Comment: How to set a limit for value reaches 9?